# Unable to upload css file from Disk

Tags: 2011, binary

When we tried to upload and save *.css files to Tridion via *Load from Disk* option it is showing below error.

We are able to upload file but unable to save.

Upon clicking Save button it is showing below error.

> Invalid value for property 'BinaryContent'. Unable to open uploaded file`

Has anyone faced such an issue?

Comment: I found a solution to this issue. To enable basic authentication under Tridion website path, WebUI>Models>TCM54 this worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

Here's some things I would check:

1) If your multimedia schema doesn't allow you to upload CSS files?

2) If the CSS is corrupted? the mimetype is correct in the actual file? - size of the file?

3) Can you download the file once uploading it (Even though you've not saved?) could there be a storage issue in your database?

Comment: I found a solution to this issue. To enable basic authentication under Tridion website path, WebUI>Models>TCM54 this worked for me.

Comment: Great if you can answer your own question, I'll give you an some trex love in the form an up-vote :)

Answer (score 1):

This may not solve your problem, but I ran into an issue with CSS files in Tridion where the multimedia type had the wrong name between environments. In my case, it was stopping content porter, but it's possible that the multimedia type has something off in it:

If you're uploading the CSS file as a binary, follow these steps.

Go to Administration > Multimedia Types
Look for `Cascading style sheet`

If it says `Cascading style sheets`, you may want to change it:
right-click, open
change the Name field appropriately.

My guess, though, is that John is probably right and either a schema doesn't have CSS as an allowed type, or that the CSS is corrupted.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to this issue. To enable basic authentication under Tridion website path, WebUI>Models>TCM54 this worked for me.

The issue was with authentication.

Comment: Are you using LDAP or SSO? Doesn't sound like a normal thing to do, to have to change authentication types...

Comment: We are using LDAP.

Comment: Thanks. According to the documentation, authorization for the CME should be set to anonymous actually. But if it works, don't change it :) http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL_Tridion_2013/task_0826E529A8DE4C5DA8C0977CC70293DE